# How to ensure smarter indentation after multiline function header?

Tags: indentation

I am using Javascript with typescript if it matters (I don't think it does for this question for reasons that I will explain later) and I have the following code:

```
veryLongFunctionName(arg1: type,
                     arg2: type,
                     arg3: type) {
  /* ... */
}
```

But when I try to make a new line in the function body it auto indents to one indent past the `arg3`'s column in the header. For example, since my indentation is set to two spaces, typing `osomeCode<ESC>` when my cursor is on `arg3` results in the following.

```
veryLongFunctionName(arg1: type,
                     arg2: type,
                     arg3: type) {
                       someCode
  /* ... */
}
```

Which is obviously not what I would like, I want its indentation level to be based upon the indentation of the function header itself. Even when I remove the typescript and javascript syntax plugins from my .vimrc, it bases its indentation on the wrong line like so.

```
veryLongFunctionName(arg1: type,
                     arg2: type,
                     arg3: type) {
                     someCode
  /* ... */
}
```

Only when I completely remove the `filetype plugin indent on` line from my .vimrc does the cursor not auto-indent to the column of `arg3` (because it doesn't indent at all).

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: The code responsible for this is your indent plugin for the filetype you're editing. `:set filetype?` will tell you the filetype, which may very well be Type Script. You'll then need to find and edit the plugin responsible. Depending on what you want, this could be very tricky to get right: your example is one of many corner cases, and it's tricky to make them all work right at the same time: that's why indentation is sub-optimal in every editor.

Comment: If it's too frustrating to deal with, as with a few obscure filetypes I've dealt with, then turning off filetype indent, and then `:set autoindent` is a reasonable compromise.